Can we define a complex norm using $L_p$ when $p = i$?
I know that $L_p$ is defined when p > 1, yet I am wondering if we were to define $L_i$ which turns out to be:
$$ \|f\|_i​=(∫_D​\|f(x)\|^idx)^{-i}$$
Then, you can basically calculate it for any vector and which gives you a complex value.
I was wondering if this makes any sense at all or there would be any use cases for such a norm?
Edit: A unit circle via complex norm.


By definition, a norm maps elements of a vector space into the real numbers, as they are totally ordered. however, you can relax this requirement and see if your mapping still satisfies other axioms of a norm, and if not, what other properties it has. after all, this is how mathematical progress is made.

I am looking into how this would be reflected on quantum theory, as myself being neither mathematician nor a physicist.

It's already a problem if you consider $p<0$ and $p\to0$. The $L^p$ for negative is already rarely used (but it exists). The limit $\lim_{p\to0+}|f|_{L^p}$ can be zero for nonzero function $f$. So your defintion need to check the behavior when $|f(x)|$ closed to $0$.
